# Google Sheets - Have Script Only Affect One Sheet, Not All

Tags: google-sheets

I am sure I am doing something wrong, but I cannot figure out what. The code below affects all of my sheets instead of just the "Pipeline" sheet that I want it to affect.

```
function onEdit() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var s1 = ss.getSheetByName("Pipeline");
   var r = s1.getActiveCell();

if(r.getColumn() === 3, r.getValue()==='Closed' ) {
  var nextCell = r.offset(0, 6);
  var printPipeline = r.offset(0,1);
  var digitalPipeline = r.offset(0,2);
  var propelPipeline = r.offset(0,3);
  printPipeline.clearContent(), digitalPipeline.clearContent(),propelPipeline.clearContent() ;
  if( nextCell.getValue() === '')//checks for blank cell
  nextCell.setValue(new Date())}
else if( r.getColumn() == 3, r.getValue()==='Lost' ) {
  var nextCell = r.offset(0, 7);//offset (row,column)
  var closedCell = r.offset(0, 6);
  var pProductsCell = r.offset(0,8);
  var pRevCell = r.offset(0,9);
  var pLengthCell = r.offset (0,10);
  var dProductsCell = r.offset(0,12);
  var dRevCell = r.offset(0,13);
  var dLengthCell = r.offset (0,14);
  var prProductsCell = r.offset(0,16);
  var prRevCell = r.offset(0,17);
  var prLengthCell = r.offset (0,18);
  closedCell.clearContent(), pProductsCell.clearContent(), pRevCell.clearContent(), pLengthCell.clearContent(), dProductsCell.clearContent(), dRevCell.clearContent(), dLengthCell.clearContent(), prProductsCell.clearContent(), prRevCell.clearContent(), prLengthCell.clearContent();      
  if( nextCell.getValue() === '')//checks for blank cell
  nextCell.setValue(new Date())}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a check for the sheet name and return if not equal to 'Pipeline':

```
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var name=ss.getSheetName()
   if(name!="Pipeline"){return}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You're a Godsend!